# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught HTTP_Request2_ConnectionException: Unable to connect to tls://bingapis.azure-api.net:443

Tags: php, image, api, azure, bing

I am working on my first script to use the new Bing search API and I keep getting an error. Based on my research it might have something to do with a certificate but I don't know where to look for a resolution. I am using a Centos 6 and 7 server with the same error result. Below is the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught HTTP_Request2_ConnectionException: Unable to connect to tls://bingapis.azure-api.net:443. Error: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://bingapis.azure-api.net:443 (Unknown error)
stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php on line 332
#0 /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php(332): HTTP_Request2_SocketWrapper->__construct('tls://bingapis....', 10, Array)
#1 /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php(128): HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Socket->connect()
#2 /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2.php(946): HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Socket->sendRequest(Object(HTTP_Request2))
#3 /usr/src/bingtest.php(33): HTTP_Request2->send()
#4 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/SocketWrapper.php on line 134
```

Can someone make a suggestion of what I should do next to troubleshoot? I am just copying and pasting the sample code from: [bing api sample php code](https://bingapis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/56b4433fcf5ff8098cef380c)

As seen below: 
( just for those who might ask i did insert my API key I generated from Bing, I just didn't want to include it here)

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new Http_Request2('https://bingapis.azure-api.net/api/v5/images/search');
$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => '{subscription key}', // I did replace this with my key
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
    'q' => 'cats',
    'count' => '10',
    'offset' => '0',
    'mkt' => 'en-us',
    'safeSearch' => 'Moderate',
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```

Comment: So after doing some initial research it looks like the url has changed to: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search but making that change did not fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is the fix for the code, the comment marks the changes

```
<?php
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

//$request = new Http_Request2('https://bingapis.azure-api.net/api/v5.0/images/search');
$request = new Http_Request2('https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search');
$url = $request->getUrl();

// ######### To Fix the SSL issue ###########
$request->setConfig(array(
    'ssl_verify_peer'   => FALSE,
    'ssl_verify_host'   => FALSE
));
// ########################################


$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'fakeasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
    'q' => 'cats',
    'count' => '10',
    'offset' => '0',
    'mkt' => 'en-us',
    'safeSearch' => 'Moderate',
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}

?>
```

Comment: Not checking the validity of an SSL certificate is not really a fix... unfortunately. Unless they only offer an untrusted SSL connection.